# How to configure Quasar in Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, quasar

I'm new to Gradle and I don't know what to do.
Here is Quasar docs about how to install Quasar through Gradle: [Quasar Docs](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#instrumentation)
There is also a template project in the page: [Template Gradle Project](https://github.com/puniverse/quasar-gradle-template)
Finally this is my `build.gradle`:

```
group 'TGAdminsBot'

version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
mainClassName = "Launcher"
idea {
    module
            {
                downloadJavadoc = true
                downloadSources = true
            }

}
dependencies {
compile 'co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:0.7.4:jdk8'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.4'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.4'
//compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
//compile 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'
compile 'co.paralleluniverse:comsat-httpclient:0.7.0'
compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.2.0'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

}
configurations {
    quasar
}
task runQuasar {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.iterator().next()}"


}
run.dependsOn runQuasar
```

And I get this Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Sobhan\Documents\IntelliJIDEAProjects\TGAdminsBot\build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'TGAdminsBot'.
> java.util.NoSuchElementException (no error message)
```

So What should I do? I'm again sorry to ask this question but I'm new to Gradle and I Googled so much before posting this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three problems.

1. `configurations` were defined before `dependencies`.
2. Two lines were needed in `dependencies`:

   ---

   compile 'co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:0.7.4:jdk8'
   quasar 'co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:0.7.4:jdk8'

   ---
3. Lack of this block:

   ---

   tasks.withType(JavaExec){
                   jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.iterator().next()}"
               }

   ---

Finally this is final `build.gradle`:

```
group 'TGAdminsBot'
version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
idea {
    module
            {
                downloadJavadoc = true
                downloadSources = true
            }

}
configurations {
    quasar
}

dependencies {
    compile 'co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:0.7.4:jdk8'
    quasar 'co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:0.7.4:jdk8'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.4'
    compile 'co.paralleluniverse:comsat-httpclient:0.7.0'
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '3.2.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

}


tasks.withType(JavaExec)
        {
            jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.iterator().next()}"
        }
task run(type: JavaExec) {

    main = 'com.sunova.bot.Launcher'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies mostly in the definition of `runQuasar` which is not a run task and thus has no `jvmArgs` property but, if you don't need it for other reasons I'm unaware of, just do [as in the Gradle template project (agent configuration)](https://github.com/puniverse/quasar-gradle-template/blob/master/gradle/agent.gradle) rather than defining `runQuasar` and declaring that `run` depends on it:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
    "-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.singleFile}" // =v, =d
]
```

If you need a separate `runQuasar` I think you'll need to declare it as a `JavaExec` task (have a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html)).

Comment: This was true, but there were some other mistakes in my code which I've discussed in my answer to my question.